# Disable ido-mode for specific commands?

Tags: emacs, ido

I've been using ido-mode for a few months, with ido-everywhere turned on, and am generally pretty happy with it.  There's one thing I wish I could change, though.  When I type <kbd>C-u M-x shell</kbd> to create a new shell buffer with a specific name, ido offers me a completion list of all of my open buffers.  If I choose one, a new shell is launched in that buffer and it's put into shell-mode, no matter what it contains.  It's hard to imagine a useful use case for this.

Is there a way to deactivate ido-mode for the shell command only?  (As well as any other similar commands I may stumble across in the future, of course.)

Comment: I know that for some commands, using the last shortcut twice disables temporarily ido (e.g, for opening a file, `C-x C-f C-f` uses the classic file open interface in the minibuffer) but I don't know with `M-x` commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heh, it turns out you'll get the same completion choices whether or not you have `ido-everywhere` enabled.

There's no built-in way to do what you want.  `ido-mode` only provides hooks for you to be able to override whether or not the `find-file` behavior is taken over by `ido` or not.  The `read-buffer` is currently *always* overridden by `ido-everywhere`.

Luckily, a little Emacs lisp can get what you want:

```
(put 'shell 'ido 'ignore)
(defadvice ido-read-buffer (around ido-read-buffer-possibly-ignore activate)
  "Check to see if use wanted to avoid using ido"
  (if (eq (get this-command 'ido) 'ignore)
      (let ((read-buffer-function nil))
        (run-hook-with-args 'ido-before-fallback-functions 'read-buffer)
        (setq ad-return-value (apply 'read-buffer (ad-get-args 0))))
    ad-do-it))
```

And for any other command you don't want following `ido-everywhere` for buffer selection can be customized by simply adding a new expression to your .emacs:

```
(put 'other-command-i-want-untouched 'ido 'ignore)
```

Comment: ...Although this doesn't quite work as written, as I discovered later.  You have to say `(setq ad-return-value (apply 'read-buffer (ad-get-args 0)))` instead of just `(apply 'read-buffer (ad-get-args 0))`.

Comment: @Sean duh, I only checked to see if the completion changed, I forgot to actually use it.  Thanks, I've updated the answer.